# React useState hook isn't triggering child component re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

In React, I have a functional component that, upon a child component button ("GenerateButton") being clicked, is supposed to kick off the render of another child component ("UsersView"), which will then display a list of users pulled from a REST API.

While debugging, I'm noticing that even though the "dataShouldLoad" state is toggled to true, it doesn't even try to start loading the code in the "UsersView" component despite "dataShouldLoad" being passed and used as prop. Why is this? What should I do?

Here is my simplified code snippet:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import GenerateButton from './GenerateButton.js';
import UsersView from './UsersView.js';

export default function GenerateReportView() {

    const [dataShouldLoad, setDataShouldLoad] = useState(false);
    const [dataHasLoaded, setDataHasLoaded] = useState(false);

    const handleGenerateButtonClick = () => {

      // By toggling this to true, I am attempting to kick off
      // the "UsersView" to fetch its data, and display here
      setDataShouldLoad(true);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {dataHasLoaded ? 
                <UsersView dataShouldLoad={dataShouldLoad} setDataHasLoaded={setDataHasLoaded}/> 

                : <h2>Click Button to Load</h2> 
            }
            
            <GenerateButton onClick={handleGenerateButtonClick}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: That's because `dataHasLoaded` is false, thus `UsersView` is not rendered yet.

Comment: Initially, yes, but in the UsersView component, I do a props.setDataHasLoaded(true). The debugger doesn't even get to this part of the code though.

Comment: `UsersView` has nothing to do with `GenerateReportView`. Different components do not share states.

Comment: But I can pass props. I understand what you were getting at though. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now, the ternary is evaluating `dataHasLoaded`, not `dataShouldLoad`. Change to `dataShouldLoad` and it will render.

Comment: But, in UsersView component, I am actually toggling dataHasLoaded with props.setDataHasLoaded(true). Regardless, the breakpoint doesn't even get to that point of the code, so are we sure that's the issue here?

Comment: But `UsersView` component is never rendering, because `dataHasLoaded` (at least on your code) is always false. If it's not rendering, nothing of its code will get executed.

Comment: Excellent explanation. I see my lapse in logic now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When you set new state for `useState` hook, the component `useState` lies in re-renders and the child components also re-render in general. In your code, `UsersView` is not even a child component of `GenerateReportView` in DOM, as you put logic- when `dataHasLoaded` is false,  `UsersView` doesn't come as a child component.